# Как перенаправить url с path в get через htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, apache

Нужно чтобы при переходе по ссылкам

```
/reserver-mes-vacances
/reserver-mes-vacances/locations-gites-de-france
/reserver-mes-vacances/locations-gites-de-france/irisit/label-jura/echappee-jurassienne/
```

Я попадал всегда на страницу **/reserver-mes-vacances**, но при этом чтобы url по которому переходили сохранялся, а строка * locations-gites-de-france/irisit/label-jura/echappee-jurassienne* попадала в get

Сайт на wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Ну кроме как парсить запрос на хуке `request` и подправлять его ничего в голову не приходит. Если бы возможен был редирект, то хук поменялся бы на `template_redirect`